# Way to do MAX(evaluation_expression, return_expression) in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group, sql-limit

I find myself often wanting to get an adjacent row value when I do a `MIN` or `MAX` statement. For example in the following statement:

```
WITH people AS (
    select 'Greg' as name, 20 as age union
    select 'Tom' as name, 17 as age
) SELECT MAX(age) FROM people;

# MAX(age)
20
```

The `MAX` function does the equivalent of: `MAX(eval_expression=age, return_expression=age)`, where it always has the same evaluation and return value (implicitly). However, I would like to find the `name` of the person with the max age. So, the conceptual syntax would be: `MAX(eval_expression=age, return_expression=name)`. This is a pattern I find myself using quite frequently and usually end up hacking something together like:

```
WITH people AS (
    select 'Greg' as name, 20 as age union
    select 'Tom' as name, 17 as age
) SELECT name FROM people NATURAL JOIN (SELECT name, MAX(age) age FROM people) _;

# name
'Greg'
```

Is there a generic way to do the `MAX(expr, return)` that I'm trying to accomplish?

---

**Update**: to provide an example where an aggregation is required:

```
with sales as (
    select DATE '2014-01-01' as date, 100 as sales, 'Fish' as product union
    select DATE '2014-01-01' as date, 105 as sales, 'Potatoes' as product union
    select DATE '2014-01-02' as date, 84 as sales, 'Salsa' as product
)  select date, max(sales) from sales group by date

# date, max(sales)
2014-01-01, 105
2014-01-02, 84
```

And how to get the equivalent of: `MAX(expr=sales, return=product)`? Something like:

```
WITH sales AS (
    select DATE '2014-01-01' as d, 100 as revenue, 'Fish' as product union
    select DATE '2014-01-01' as d, 105 as revenue, 'Potatoes' as product union
    select DATE '2014-01-02' as d, 84 as revenue, 'Salsa' as product
) SELECT d AS date, product FROM sales NATURAL JOIN (SELECT d, MAX(revenue) AS revenue FROM sales GROUP BY d) _;

# date, product
2014-01-01, Potatoes
2014-01-02, Salsa
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something here -
use `limit` with `order by`:

```
WITH people AS (
    select 'Greg' as name, 20 as age union
    select 'Tom' as name, 17 as age
)
SELECT name
FROM people 
ORDER BY age DESC
LIMIT 1;

# name
'Greg'
```

Comment: I'm an idiot for not seeing that...thank you for that. Actually -- let me put up a better example where it may be necessary to use an aggregate expression.

Comment: @David542 . . . If you want one row -- which is how I interpret your question -- then this is the best answer.  That was your original question.  You should have accepted this answer and asked a new question, rather than invalidating this answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks. I was debating with myself whether or not I should delete this answer since the the OP actually intended something else. However, the OP did edit the question in a such a way that didn't entirely invalidating my answer but rather invalidated the question itself - instead of a single, focused question now there are two different questions - one is answerable using `order by` and `limit` and the other using `first_value` - so I decided not to delete it after all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `first_value()`, I would recommend:

```
select distinct date, 
    first_value(product) over(partition by date order by sales desc) top_product
from sales
```

No need for aggregation here, nor for a frame specification in the window function. The window function walks the dataset starting from the row with the greatst sales, so all rows in the partition get the same `top_product` assigned. Then `distinct` retains only one row per partition.

But basically, this ends up as a greatest-n-per group problem, where you want the row with the greatest sale for each date. The `first_value()` solution does not scale well if you want more than one column on that row. A typical solution is to rank records in a subquery, then filter. Again, no aggregation is needed, that's filtering logic only:

```
select *
from (
    select s.*
        row_number() over(partition by date order bys ales desc) rn
    from sales
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use an unbounded window function such as [`FIRST_VALUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_first-value), where you can sort the date partition by sales. Here would be an example:

```
;WITH sales AS (
    select DATE '2014-01-01' as date, 100 as sales, 'Fish' as product union
    select DATE '2014-01-01' as date, 105 as sales, 'Potatoes' as product union
    select DATE '2014-01-01' as date, 103 as sales, 'Lettuce' as product union
    select DATE '2014-01-02' as date, 84 as sales, 'Salsa' as product
)  

SELECT DISTINCT date, LAST_VALUE(product) OVER (
    partition by date
    order by sales
    -- Default: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html
    -- rows between unbounded preceding and current row
    rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
) top_product
 FROM sales group by date;

# date, top_product
'2014-01-01', 'Potatoes'
'2014-01-02', 'Salsa'
```

I think the `subselect` might be easier to read (at least for me), but this is another option. You'd have to check on the performance of the two but I'd think the analytic function (without the not-indexeable join) would be much faster.

Comment: Yes, `first_value` is the go-to solution for this scenario. You should also probably use `distinct`, though.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I just noticed that kink on my end. Actually, I was going to ask: why does the analytic function act differently when there is `GROUP BY` vs when there is a `DISTINCT` in the select clause?

Comment: I don't know. Personally, I almost never worked with MySql - most of my work is with SQL Server - and I don't rememver a difference between `group by` and `distinct` there. Maybe MySql does things different?

Comment: @David542: conceptually, the window function executes after the aggregation, but before `distinct`. See my answer for a simpler way to express this.